# Using RabbitMQ for Background Jobs?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, message-queue

I already have a group of background jobs in my web API handled by Hangfire,
the client asks to use rabbitMQ for these background jobs however I think this will be no sense to use rabbitMQ for this purpose because my jobs didn't call any external APIs it  calling third-party libraries (for ex: upload on S3 AWS) , is using rabbitMQ for background jobs will improve application resiliency & scalability at this case ??